# Input datas into a ZZFeatureMap

Tags: qiskit, embedding

I want to encode classical data into quantum data.
For that, I know qiskit has a feature map : the ZZFeatureMap. So I build a quantum circuit with this ZZFeatureMap following qiskit's documentation:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
feature_map = ZZFeatureMap(2, reps=1)
ansatz = RealAmplitudes(2)
qc.compose(feature_map, inplace=True)
qc.compose(ansatz, inplace=True)
qc.measure([0,1], [0,1])
```

[image]

But now, let's say I have the classical data : data=[10, 42]

How can I input my classical data into the ZZFeatureMap circuit ?
My goal is then to run simulations to see what the encoding does.

Comment: I think I just found out : I added bind_parameters(data) in my feature_map. If someone can confirm that's how you do ?

Answer (score 1):

As you already noticed, we use [`QuantumCircuit.bind_parameters()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.bind_parameters.html) method to encode our classical dataset as rotations on [`ZZFeatureMap`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.ZZFeatureMap.html)'s parameterized gates.

```
data = [0.1, 0.2]
feature_map = ZZFeatureMap(2, reps=1)
feature_map = feature_map.bind_parameters(data) # <== here

qc = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
qc.compose(feature_map, inplace=True)

ansatz = RealAmplitudes(2)
qc.compose(ansatz, inplace=True)

qc.measure([0,1], [0,1])
```

**Note**: since the data is encoded as angle rotations, you need to normalize it to be in the interval $(0, 2\pi]$.

ZZ feature map is introcuded in the paper "[Supervised learning with quantum enhanced feature spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.11326)" by Havlíček et. la. (2019)

For more details, see: [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/platypus/blob/main/notebooks/quantum-machine-learning/encoding.ipynb) and [here](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-community-tutorials/blob/master/machine_learning/custom_feature_map.ipynb).